# How to find specific text in text file, and add additional text in the following line in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, text, replace

I need to open a txt file, find an specific string, write several lines right below it, save the resulting file and close it. This is what I have so far:

```
Sub EditMyTXT()

Dim FileNum As Integer
Dim DataLine As String

FileNum = FreeFile()
Open "E:\Host.txt" For Input As #FileNum

While Not EOF(FileNum)
    Line Input #FileNum, DataLine
        If DataLine = "TextToFind" Then
             move to the next line
             write text "TextToWriteBelow TextToFind"
             move to the next line
             write text "MoreTextToWriteBelow"
        Else: End If
Wend

 Save FileNum
 Close FileNum

End Sub
```

I can't find a way to open a txt file in a mode that would allow me to read an write to it. Any ideas, suggestions?

Comment: Open a new file for output and copy the content to that new file, adding new content as needed.

Comment: While driving from home I got the same idea. I will implement it tomorrow and re-post. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also read the text file into a string variable, change that and write it back like that

```
Sub EditMyTXT_Full()

    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim DataLine As String
    Dim fileName As String

    fileName = "D:\TEMP\HOST.TXT"

    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open fileName For Input As #FileNum

    Dim textData As String
    ' read the complete file into textdata
    textData = Input$(LOF(FileNum), FileNum)
    Close #FileNum

    Dim searchLine As String
    Dim newLines As String

    searchLine = "Test"
    newLines = "New Line 1" & vbCrLf & "New Line 2"

    Dim vdat As Variant
    vdat = Split(textData, vbCrLf)

    Dim i As Long
    ' This is the loop through the lines but completely in memory
    For i = LBound(vdat) To UBound(vdat)
        If vdat(i) = searchLine Then
            vdat(i) = vdat(i) & vbCrLf & newLines
        End If
    Next i

    textData = Join(vdat, vbCrLf)

    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open fileName For Binary Access Write As #FileNum
    ' write the text back in one step
    Put #FileNum, , textData
    Close #FileNum

End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent, it does the job!

Comment: How can I modify the code such as "newLines" is inserted in the second row below the "vdat(i) = searchLine", preserving what is in line i+1. something like this:

Comment: You would probabyl need to modify the for loop to something like that `v1Dat(i + 1) = v1Dat(i + 1) & vbCrLf & newLines`. And do not forget to `Redim` the array beforehand like `ReDim Preserve v1Dat(UBound(v1Dat) + 1)`